# listView inside a ViewFlipper - scrolling problems

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, scroll, viewflipper

I'm having some trouble with my `litView` inside my `viewFlipper`.

```
    // GestureDetector
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // Right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                IconManager.INSTANCE.leftSwipe();
                vf.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                vf.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                vf.showNext();
                System.out.println("SWIIINGG!!");
                // Left to right swipe
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                IconManager.INSTANCE.rightSwipe();
                vf.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                vf.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                vf.showPrevious();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e("Item Click","Item Click");

        Intent intentAgenda = new Intent (Activity_Main.this, AgendaSelected.class);
        //intentAgenda.putExtra("LECTURE_NAME", homeAgendaListAdapter.getItemId(3));
        startActivity(intentAgenda);
        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    }
}
```

This code enables me to flip among the views in the flipper and scroll in the lists within the different flips. However, this makes my **entire app** clickable. Even if I `singleTap` on a blank surface, it registers a click, and sends me to where the `Intent intentAgenda = new Intent` wants to send me. This should only happen when I tap on an item within the `listView`!

What can I do to get the listener on the specific lists to only listen "on the lists" and not the entire app? I believe that the problem lies within the `public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed`, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried the above but one solution that actually work is to create a new OnItemClickListener and then setOnItemClickListener(your item click listener) on your lists.
That would be to not use single tap in your case but just create a new on itemclick listener like this but more stylish:

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Intent intentAgenda = new Intent (Activity_Main.this, AgendaSelected.class);
            //      //          intentAgenda.putExtra("LECTURE_NAME", homeAgendaListAdapter.getItemId(3));
            startActivity(intentAgenda);
        }
    });
```

If you want to create more lists you can create a new item click listener and just point every list to it.

Comment: thanks man! Not so efficient coding, but what the heck... it works! :D

Comment: I'm guessing since in this instance the code requires you create a new OnItemClickListener for every list. This is probably not how you should code it though if you have many lists in one activity. This is just a simple example. Although I've not tried it and it was a while this was brought up, I'm guessing you should implement OnItemClickListener and create a case for the lists which should have a clickListener on it. That way you only should have to create one instance of the OnItemClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

Since the ViewFlipper containing the lists has the same gestureListener, everything within the viewflipper that is tapped will trigger the onSingleTapConfirmed() method.. Try registering the lists on a seperate gesturelistner aswell to handle the taps only :) Feels like the problem isn't in this codeblock but rather where the gestureListners etc is set.